# Jquery ajax in loop and assign id in success function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a foreach loop on some items with an id, in which I have an ajax call. In success function, I want to attribute each response to its corresponding id. How can I do that? Because in succes my id is lost. How can I do something like that:

```
for (i=0; i<items_to_print.length; i++) {
  var item = items_to_print[i];

  jQuery.ajax({
    url: item.url,
    dataType: "json",
    data: item.data,
    success: function(response, i) {
      items_to_print[i]['response'] = response;
    }
  });
}
```

Thank you,

Comment: Do not make AJAX calls in a loop. It will flood your server with requests and cause performance problems. To both avoid this server performance issue, and also fix your problem, aggregate all the data in to a single request and send it once. Then you can deal with a single response which includes the amendments you need to make to all relevant DOM elements.

Comment: I'd love to do that but I have no choice to call this script working this way... :( I need a quick solution, even if it's dirty

Comment: I don't see you using any `id` property here. Is it a property of `item`? What is the exact problem you are getting?

Comment: it is just to assign response to the correct corresponding i index of the items_to_print array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is to slow the loop down - only go to the next item in the array once you get a response.

```
var items_to_print = [{url:"https...",data:{}},{url:"https...",data:{}},{url:"https...",data:{}}];

var count = 0;
makeCall();
function makeCall(){
    if(count >= items_to_print.length){return;}
    var _item = items_to_print[count];
    jQuery.ajax({
    url: item.url,
    dataType: "json",
    data: item.data,
    success: _response
  });
}

function _response(response){
   items_to_print[count]['response'] = response;
   count++;
   makeCall();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here is that, when the `success` is called, `i` points to the last position of the array, so all responses are added to the last item (and only the last one that finishes perdures). This happens because the closure that `success` creates captures `i`, but the variable itself, not its current value when the function is defined, so all closures share the same reference to a variable -- a variable that is being modified by the loop. To prevent this, you can use `forEach` instead of a `for` loop:

```
items_to_print.forEach(function(item) {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: item.url,
        dataType: "json",
        data: item.data,
        success: function(response, i) {
           item.response = response;
        }
    });
});
```

Doing it this way, for each item in the array you are calling a function, and so the `item` variable is different for each call, so `success` can capture it without a problem as it always points to the same object -- the one for which the request was made.